# how to download VMware for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have windows 10 , and I need to use vmware workstation, i have checked on internet , but even the lastest version of
VMware Workstation 11.1.2.2780323 doesnot support windows 10. can anyone tell me any alternative of vmware workstation  ? or send me a link for virtual machine software? thanks it would be a great help.

Answer (score -1):

VMware Workstation 12 is the latest version and it supports Windows 10 as both the host and guest OS. The second feature listed on the [features page](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/features.html) is "Built for Windows 10 and more"

Windows 10 as the VM Host > [System Requirements](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/faqs/install-requirements.html#system_requirements)

> Host operating systems* (64-bit):
>
> - Windows 10
> - Windows 8
> - [...]

Windows 10 as a VM Guest > [Supported Guest Operating Systems](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/faqs/install-requirements.html#supported_guest)

> VMware Workstation 12 Pro supports hundreds of 32-bit and 64-bit guest operating systems from Microsoft DOS through **Windows 10**, Windows NT Server through Windows Server 2012 R2, Ubuntu 15.04, various other flavors of Linux.

Download:
[VMware Workstation Pro Download Page](https://www.vmware.com/go/downloadworkstation)

Alternative: VirtualBox 5 also supports Windows 10. [Press Release](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/oracle-vm-virtualbox-5-070915.html)

> The 5.0 release supports the latest guest or host operating systems including: Mac OS X Yosemite, **Windows 10**, Oracle Linux, Oracle Solaris [...]

Download: [VirtualBox Download Page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)